# Can someone give me an example of a Unmanaged C++ HTML Client with proxy support?

Tags: c++, html, http

Can someone give me an example of a Unmanaged C++ HTML Client with proxy support?

I want to do some get and posts inside my unmanaged c++ programs, ideally I would like to allow for proxy server configuration, or just use the IE defaults.

I am not looking for hand outs, just something to go by, as I can't seem to find too much on this.

Comment: You probably mean you want to have some sample code for an HTTP client in C++, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384096.aspx) to get the proxy configuration and then use the HTTP stack of your choice. I would avoid implementing your own psuedo HTTP stack, getting it right is more work then you probably think.

Answer (score 2):

What, [seriously?](http://www.mozilla.com/)

Comment: I am looking for a code snippet of a socket creation, with a socket send() followed by a recv()

Comment: Well, then you should edit your question and make this clear!  People generally do not read through all comments to find the correct question...

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp).  It does not deliver out-of-the-box what you request, there are more complete libraries out there, it just happens that I don't know them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on Windows, you can use [WinHttp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384273(VS.85).aspx) to write a C++ HTTP client, I just finished implementing a client with it here at work.

WinHttp is a fairly straightforward API to use and takes care of all the HTTP communication details for you.